# Indentation of second paragraph inside \item list

Tags: indentation, enumerate

How to make a list like below:

```
1. this is my first paragraph in first \item.
   nextline, same paragraph

   this is my second paragraph in first \item.
   nextline, same paragraph    

2. this is my first paragraph in second \item.
   nextline, same paragraph
```

my current result is:

```
1. this is my first paragraph in first \item.
   nextline, same paragraph

       this is my second paragraph in first \item.
   nextline, same paragraph

2. this is my first paragraph in second \item.
   nextline, same paragraph
```

I've try to use `\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]` but it only change the first paragraph in my list.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You need to provide a minimum working example that demonstrates this behavior.  I cannot recreate it.

Comment: The default behaviour of lists like `enumerate` and `itemize` (with or without [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)) is to have no indentation for (all) paragraphs set within an `\item`. You must be doing something different than normal here. What is that...?

Comment: I'm using thesis template from campus, I've searched in the template using keyword `enum` to find any setting that may change the behavior and I found nothing. After looking @Werner comments I search again using keyword `item` and found a lot of setting made in the template, Thank You

Comment: The parameter for this is `\listparindent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\noindent` at the beginning of the second paragraph inside the `enumerate` environment. Here is the minimal code to get what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item 
   this is my first paragraph in first \\item.
   nextline, same paragraph

   \noindent
   this is my second paragraph in first \\item.
   nextline, same paragraph    

  \item 
   this is my first paragraph in second \\item.
   nextline, same paragraph

   \noindent
   this is my second paragraph in second \\item.
   nextline, same paragraph    

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you want to remove the first line indentation globally, you can use

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

in the preamble of your document.

Comment: But in `article` there is no indent on these paragraphs anyway, so the `\noindent` has no effect.

Comment: True. We have no idea of the thesis style of his campus. I was just showing a way to address the problem.